# AWS Kinesis Lambda Scheduled Pull Invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

There seems to be no way to tell lambdas to pull records in a scheduled manner.

This means that my lambda function never gets invoked unless the size of records meets the batch specification.

I'd like to my lambda function to get invoked eagerly so that it can pull records after a specified time elapses as well.

Imagine that you are building a real time analytics service that do not fill the specified batch size for a long time during off-peaks.

Is there any workaround to pull records periodically?

Comment: Can't you just schedule your Lambda function to run on a schedule using Lambda Scheduled Events? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: I think this invokes the function with Schedule event rather than Kinesis event. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html

Comment: I guess I can trigger the Scheduled event and push dummy records to the Kinesis stream to fill the batch size to initiate the lambda function...

Comment: You could set your batch size to 1 but you should be very careful in doing that.  It's very inefficient.  You can only perform 4 read operations per second and if you have a lot of events being written to your stream you will never be able to clear your events.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that my lambda function never gets invoked unless the size of records meets the batch specification.

That is not correct to my knowledge - **can you provide the documentation that says so?**

### To my knowledge

`AWS` uses a daemon for polling the stream and check for new records. The daemon is what triggers the `Lambda` and it happens in one of the two cases:

1. Batch size crossed the specified limit (the one configured in `Lambda`).
2. Certain time had passed (don't know how much exactly) and current batch **is not empty**.

I had done a massive use of `Kinesis` and `Lambda`, I have configured the batch limit to 500 records (per invocation).

I have had invocations with less than 500 records, sometimes even ~20 records - **this is a fact**.